# How to connect to a WPA2 enterprise with nmcli in a non interactive mode?

Tags: network-manager, wpa-supplicant, wpa, nmcli

I am able to connect with `nmcli` to a WPA enterprise network only in an interactive mode launched by

```
 nmcli con edit id MYNAME
```

`nmcli` refuses to change 802-1x values while not in edit mode:

```
nmcli c modify MYNAME wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap 
Error: Failed to modify connection 'MYNAME': 802-1x: 'wpa-eap' security requires '802-1x' setting presence
```

How would you suggest to connect without "setting presence" which I don't want since I want to automatize the connection setting process.

Answer (score 6):

Kind of a late response, but maybe someone stumbles upon this same problem and may be looking for a solution.

### Proper Solution

EDIT: Looks like I was wrong with both solutions, since I happened to get exact same error. However I found a solution to this - simply set all `802-1x` settings in one line, e.g.:

`nmcli c modify <connection_name> 802-1x.eap <eap_mode> 802-1x.identity <username> 802-1x.phase2-auth <auth_type>`

For what I've tested, these 3 settings are a minimum to setting `802-1x` property. I will leave the previous answer, for I believe these still might be applicable as part of the solution.

### Previous Solution (for reference)

This looks like you are trying to set `wifi-sec.key-mgmt` connection property before setting `802.1x` values. To put it simplier, you must put your edits in specified order, with `802.1x` settings first, and `wifi-sec` keys later.

However, if that is not the case - do you have your connection already added? You can add an empty template using following command:

`nmcli con add type wifi [ifname <interface_name>] [con-name <connection_name_shown>] [ssid <ssid_of_wifi_connection>]`

All parts (not sure about `con-name`) in `[]` can be skipped, but you would need to add them through `modify` command later on for the network to run, unless you only have 1 WLAN interface.

Comment: You've just restored my faith in humanity!  A first post that is of excellent quality!  **;-)**  +1

Comment: @Fabby I've been struggling with similiar issue, and came upon this question somehow, thought I could share with community ;)